# How to target container in GitHub actions?

Tags: docker, github-actions

I am trying to use GitHub Actions to fire up a Postgres container for my tests. I have a script called `build.sh` that gets called when `npm run build` is called via GitHub actions. This script calls upon `restore-schema.sh` (shown below).

The issue here is when `restore-schema.sh` gets ran, I keep getting `Error: no such container: postgres`. GitHub actions is naming the container some arbitrary string. Is there not a way I can run docker exec on an image or somehow name the postgres container that GitHub actions is creating? I've looked through both documentations to no avail.

How should I go about this? I noticed that in the *Docker run ps* screenshot, it shows command `docker-entrypoint.sh`. Should I use this instead? Do I specify the Dockerfile inside `.github/workflows/`?

I tried to include as much relevant information as possible - comment if you need any other information please.

**Screenshots from GitHub Actions**

- [Initialize containers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiGb5.jpg)
- [Docker run ps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGHuP.png) **<- docker ps showing name postgres**
- [Run npm run build --if-present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mJyu.jpg) **<- WHERE THE ISSUE IS OCCURING**

*build.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh

# Import core db schema
./.deploy/postgres/restore-schema.sh
```

*.deploy/postgres/restore-schema.sh*

```
#!/bin/sh


docker exec -it postgres psql \
--username postgres \
--password dev \
coredb < .deploy/postgres/db-schema.sql
```

*.github/workflows/test-api-gateway.yml*

```
name: API Gateway CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master, develop ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services: # Serivce containers to run with `container-job`
      # Label used to access the service container
      postgres:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: postgres
        # Provide the password for postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: postgres
          POSTGRES_DB: coredb
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dev
        # Set health checks to wait until postgres has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5 
        ports:
          - 5432:5432

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: docker ps
    - run: chmod +x build.sh .deploy/postgres/restore-schema.sh
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: npm test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the --name option

```
options: >-
  --health-cmd pg_isready
  --health-interval 10s
  --health-timeout 5s
  --health-retries 5
  --name postgres
```

https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservices

jobs.<job_id>.services.options: Additional Docker container resource options. For a list of options, see "docker create options."

Another solution I've seen is using last created container

```
docker exec -it $(docker ps --latest --quiet) bash
```

Comment: I ended up going a different route by essentially just having a wrapper container. Both solutions suffice but I appreciate the research.